# Get file name when uploading file using ajax in Struts2

Tags: ajax, struts2, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying  fileupload using ajax in a struts2 framework webapp. I am using the "fileupload" interceptor  in the action mapping, i am getting the file content in the action, but not the uploaded fileName i.e.,

```
private File file; // + its setters & getters methods.
private String fileName; // + its setter & getters methods.

System.Out.println(file.getName()); //prints some .tmp file
```

The **fileName** variable is null.

Do i have to specify any file Details while making an ajax call to get the FileName of the uploaded file ?

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

if the "name" attribute of the  on your page is "xxx"

```
private File xxx;
private String xxxContentType;
private String xxxFileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

[FileUpload Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/FileUploadInterceptor.html)

You should provide setter method appropriately. Follow naming convention carefully. Refer above link

[Struts2 FileUpload Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/)